# Displaying an ICollection in a View

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a model that was auto-generated from my SQL database.

```
class Organization
{
    public Organization()
    {
        this.ContactTitles = new HashSet<ContactTitle>();
        this.OrganizationAddresses = new HashSet<OrganizationAddress>();
        this.OrganizationBusinessTypes = new HashSet<OrganizationBusinessType>();
        this.OrganizationCountries = new HashSet<OrganizationCountry>();
        this.OrganizationEmails = new HashSet<OrganizationEmail>();
        this.OrganizationMemberships = new HashSet<OrganizationMembership>();
        this.OrganizationNotes = new HashSet<OrganizationNote>();
        this.OrganizationPhones = new HashSet<OrganizationPhone>();
        this.OrganizationWebsites = new HashSet<OrganizationWebsite>();
        this.Contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();
        this.OrganizationIndustryCodes = new HashSet<OrganizationIndustryCode>();
    }

    public int OrganizationID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ContactTitle> ContactTitles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrganizationAddress> OrganizationAddresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrganizationBusinessType> OrganizationBusinessTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrganizationCountry> OrganizationCountries { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrganizationEmail> OrganizationEmails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrganizationMembership> OrganizationMemberships { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrganizationNote> OrganizationNotes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrganizationPhone> OrganizationPhones { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrganizationWebsite> OrganizationWebsites { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrganizationIndustryCode> OrganizationIndustryCodes { get; set; }
 }
```

In my Organization View, on my Index page - it is strongly typed to my Organization Model.

I am trying to displaying the Membership information, on the Organization index page, that I believe should be in the ICollection. Unless I am miss-interpreting what that does.

When I go to put a `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrganizationMemberships.` to grab the data in the OrganizationMembership table, it does not show up on IntelliSense. I only need to be able to display the data, I don't have to submit any changes with a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the model is an enumerable type -- `@model PagedList.IPagedList<VAGTC.Models.Organization>` -- you'll need to iterate through them in your main view:

```
@foreach (var organization in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => organization)
}
```

Next, create a [display template](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html) for the class `Organization`.  Under `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` add a view `Organization.cshtml`:

```
@model VAGTC.Models.Organization
```

Now this is the main view that renders your class.  Here you can iterate over the membership items:

```
@foreach (var membership in Model.OrganizationMemberships)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => membership)
}
```

Now again, create a partial view for the `OrganizationMembership` class by adding `OrganizationMembership.cshtml` under `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates`.

Comment: I have `@model PagedList.IPagedList<VAGTC.Models.Organization>` to utilize the PagedList stuff. So this would be why I cannot do anything with OrganizationMemberships on my Organization View? Model.OrganizationMembership does not work either - it states that it does not contain the definition.

Comment: @kifi what's the model type declared at the top of your View?

Comment: `@model PagedList.IPagedList<VAGTC.Models.Organization>`

This is declared at the top of my View

Comment: @kifi I changed my answer based on this info -- please see above.  The key is to learn about using partial view display templates -- if you have a display template partial view for a class type, then MVC automatically uses that partial view whenever it finds `DisplayFor` with the class type.